Functorial reduction to path-connected spaces when considering fundamental groups
I'm studying general topology and a question has come to my mind.
I know that, to some extents, when considering path-theoretical notions in a space, it is indeed not a significant loss of generality (at least theoretically) to consider only path-connected spaces, since, for example, the image of a path lies into one and only one path-connected component. In particular, I'm interested in how this has implications for the fundamental group of a space: at a first glance, I guess that fundamental groups of a pointed space (X,x) is isomorphic to the one (F(X,x)) of the connected component of x (as a subspace, still pointed in x).
Not having a sound background in category theory, I'm asking for advice to make this connection formal. I presume the correspondence I've mentioned induces a functor F from Top to the category D of path-connected spaces, and that the "fundamental group" functor G somehow factorises (is equivalent to?) the one obtained composing F with the restiction of G to D. Can anyone provide a more precise insight of the situation, of provide reference about it?

The fundamental group defines a functor $\pi_1\colon \mathrm{Top}* \to \mathrm{Grp}$ where $\mathrm{Top}$ is the category of pointed topological spaces and basepoint-preserving maps. There is then a functor $R\colon \mathrm{Top}_ \to \mathrm{Top}_*$ taking a space to the path component containing the basepoint and maps to the restriction to said component (convince yourself this is well-defined), and together these satisfy $\pi_1 = \pi_1 \circ R$. Is that what you're looking for?

@BenSteffan Yes, that's in some ways what I imagined, except from the fact that this account hides (or, at least, does not highlight) the fact that through R one reduces to path-connected spaces.

The very definition of $R$ depends on path components, which are path connected by default, so I don't think this is hiding anything.

Another option is to invent a new category, let's call it $\text{PCTop}*$, whose objects are pointed, path connected topological spaces. Then the functor described in the comment of @BenSteffan can be reconfigured as a functor $R : \text{Top}* \to \text{PCTop}_*$.

@BenSteffan Why not an official answer?

@PaulFrost Because I (a) wanted to see whether I understood the question correctly, and then (b) couldn't find the time to write it up into an answer. Will do so now :)

To sum up what has been said in the comments:
If you want to consider the fundamental group as a functor, it should have the shape $\newcommand{\Top}{\mathrm{Top}}\newcommand{\Grp}{\mathrm{Grp}}\pi_1\colon \Top_* \to \Grp$ where $\Top_*$ is the category of pointed topological spaces and pointed maps, taking a pointed space $(X, x_0)$ to the fundamental group $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ based at $x_0$.
You can then define a functor $R\colon \Top_* \to \Top_*$ taking a pointed space to the path component containing the basepoint (pointed at that same basepoint) and maps to their restriction to said component. The fact that $\pi_1$ only depends on the path component of the basepoint can then be expressed as
$$
    \pi_1 = \pi_1 \circ R
$$
As has been pointed out by Lee Mosher, you could go even further: Let $\newcommand{\Toppc}{\Top^{\mathrm{p.c.}}} \Toppc_* \subset \Top_*$ denote the subcategory of all path-connected pointed spaces. By restricting $\pi_1$ we get a functor $\pi_1'\colon \Toppc_* \to \Grp$, and $R$ naturally restricts to a functor $R'\colon \Top_* \to \Toppc_*$ since its image already lies in $\Toppc_*$. Similar to before, you then obtain the equality
$$
    \pi_1 = \pi_1' \circ R'
$$
the only difference being that path-connectedness is now made explicit in the notation.

One thing that I should point out explicitly is the use of equal signs above: Generally one should be very careful with equalities vs. (natural) isomorphisms, but here the equal signs are justified since the groups after restriction are still defined by the exact same data (though your mileage may vary).
Furthermore, I want to warn against categorification for its own sake: There's usually little point in expressing the fact that $\pi_1$ only depends on the path component of the basepoint categorially since (a) $\pi_1$ is something very concrete and (b) you're rarely using it in a strictly categorial sense. It's a bit of a line one has to walk: For instance, it's very useful to know that $\pi_1$ is a functor (a categorial fact), and that $\pi_1$ only depends on the path-component of the basepoint (a topological fact), but it's not really useful to categorify this latter fact, because (say) you're rarely if ever using $\pi_1$ in some sort of abstract functor calculus.
In particular, since the answer to the question "can I categorify this somehow" is almost always yes, one should really stop to think whether it's worth the trade-off of introducing new notation, new categories, new functors to express some fact purely categorially.

Finally, let me invite you to take an afternoon and sit down with a copy of Riehl's Category Theory in Context and read through just the first chapter. There really isn't much to the basics of category theory, and pretty much anybody who's ever taken a proof-based course should be able to understand what categories and functors are. In particular, you really don't need much of a background to be able to answer questions like this.

I thank you for the punctual answer and for your suggestion. Just to make things clear, I am aware that I could myself verify the identity mentioned in spite of my lack of categorical experience; I posed the question seeking not only for clarification but possibly also for further viewpoints which, on the other hand, I cannot elaborate myself for the time being.

@AmandaWealth You're welcome! The question is fine, I just (a) felt a need to warn against getting yourself stuck trying to categorify everything you come across; sometimes people learning about category theory for the first time end up trying to put everything they come across into categorial language and ultimately put a lot of time and effort into something that's not very useful altogether, and I'd like to nudge people towards not doing that; and, at the same time...

...(b) urge you to actually take the time to properly learn about the very basics, i.e. categories and functors (and maybe natural transformations) because the material is much more accessible than some people might make it seem, and it's something you need to get yourself acquainted with sooner or later anyhow (at least if you do things like algebraic topology).
